# shopware 6 how do I query and capture other details related to an order using their ids

Tags: php, symfony, events, shopware6

Hello I have been working with a shopware project. I am working using event subscribers. in my class I attempt to pick the latest made orders on the store

`CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent::class => 'OnOrderReceived',`

`public function OnOrderReceived(CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent $event): void`

I am able to get some details such as details about the order. but then when I try to capture details with regarding

`"billing address".  getOrder()->getBillingAddress()`

`'salesChannel     getOrder()->getSalesChannel()`

they are null but I am able to get their respective IDS

`$event->getOrder()->getSalesChannelId(),`

`$event->getOrder()->getBillingAddressId()`

please how do I query using this IDS to get their respective details?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Inject](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/dependency-injection) `sales_channel.repository` and `order_address.repository` respectively into your subscriber. Then use the repositories to fetch the respective entity.

```xml
<services>
    <service id="Swag\BasicExample\Subscriber\MySubscriber">
        <argument type="service" id="sales_channel.repository"/>
        <argument type="service" id="order_address.repository"/>
        <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Swag\BasicExample\Subscriber;

use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Event\CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class MySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly EntityRepository $salesChannelRepository,
        private readonly EntityRepository $orderAddressRepository
    ) {
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent::class => 'orderPlaced',
        ];
    }

    public function orderPlaced(CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent $event): void
    {
        $salesChannel = $this->salesChannelRepository
            ->search(new Criteria([$event->getOrder()->getSalesChannelId()]), $event->getContext())
            ->first();
        
        $orderBillingAddress = $this->orderAddressRepository
            ->search(new Criteria([$event->getOrder()->getBillingAddressId()]), $event->getContext())
            ->first();
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: hello @dneustadt thank you for your explanation. was trying out what you explained, but then an exception is throw from the construct in MyCustomBundle\Subscriber\MySubscriber::__construct(): Argument #1 ($salesChannelRepository) must be of type Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository, Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger given. what could be the issue

Comment: You're injecting the wrong service as the first argument. The order of the arguments in `services.xml` is important.

Comment: thank you very much for the solution,  $salesChannel returns information but that of  $orderBillingAddress returns empty when I make query. what could this mean, im sure I had that filled up while making my order

Comment: of all the repositories, I couldn't get the shipping and billing repositories to work, it returned an empty dataset

Comment: never mind I got it to work using customer address repository